# Reusing memory stream in Func<>

Tags: c#, stream

I have  a method called from  `using` block which takes few arguments. One of them is `Func<HttpContent> myMetohd`. After `myMethod()` (in some cases) I want to reuse IDisposable from it.
I know that we can set start index in MemStreams on 0 index.
Is it possible to do it in my case?

That's a skeleton of my code. HttpContent has a memStream inside. After first using stream is read, so i can't use it second time.
I can't do Clone() on that stream cuz it's too heavy.

```
using (var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent())
{
    //some code here
    myMethod(args,()=>formData);
}

public void myMethod(string args,Func<HttpContent> func){
// some code here
func(); //first usage

//more code here

//in some cases..

func();//second usage which throws an exception - cuz stream inside HttpContent has been read
}
```

Comment: *Is it possible to do it in my case?* - it's not possible to say without knowing specifically what your case is. Can you include a [mcve] showing what you've tried and what issues you're having with that?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. What is the relationship between `Func<HttpContext>` and `MemoryStream`?

Comment: I posted skeleton of my code below. HttpContent contains MemStream.

Comment: "below" is a section reserved solely for _answers_. You should [_edit_ your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71793953/edit).

Comment: So i added "above". Could you help me now?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not, you cannot read a HttpContext Request Stream more than once.

But, if the stream is large, maybe write it to a temporary file and then read from the file?

```cs
var tempFile = Path.GetTempFilename();

try
{
  using (var fs = File.OpenWrite(tempFile))
  {
    // Write the body to a file
    await HttpContext.Request.Body.CopyToAsync(fs);
  }

  // Use the data in the file to do what you need
  ...
}
finally
{
  // Ensure that file is deleted at the end
  File.Delete(tempFile);
}
```